# Анимация svg стрелочек

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такие стрелочки:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}

path {
  fill: rgba(255,255,255, 0);
  stroke: #fff;
}

g:hover path {
  fill: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <svg width="630" height="45" viewBox="0 0 630 45" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M74.7071 44.521H0.779053L22.0341 22.32L0.779053 0.118988H74.7071L95.9621 22.32L74.7071 44.521Z" fill="white"/>

      </a>
    </g>


    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M152.214 44.521H80.538L101.793 22.32L80.538 0.118988H152.214L173.469 22.32L152.214 44.521Z" fill="white"/>
      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M204.807 44.521H157.868L179.124 22.32L157.868 0.118988H204.807L226.062 22.32L204.807 44.521Z" fill="white"/>

      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M294.01 44.521H210.282L231.538 22.32L210.282 0.118988H294.01L315.265 22.32L294.01 44.521Z" fill="white"/>
      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M343.138 44.521H300.006L321.261 22.32L300.006 0.118988H343.138L364.394 22.32L343.138 44.521Z" fill="white"/>
     </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M433.517 44.521H348.521L369.775 22.32L348.521 0.118988H433.517L454.772 22.32L433.517 44.521Z" fill="white"/>
      </a>
    </g>
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M527.8 44.521H438.998L460.254 22.32L438.998 0.118988H527.8L549.056 22.32L527.8 44.521Z" fill="white"/>
      </a>
    </g>
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M607.952 44.521H533.738L554.994 22.32L533.738 0.118988H607.952L629.207 22.32L607.952 44.521Z" fill="white"/>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

**Вопрос:** как реализовать такую анимацию -->
При загрузке страницы начинают выезжать слева на право стрелки поочередно.
Каждый сегмент стрелки «загорается» белым по очереди слева направо, текст при этом меняет цвет с белого на серый
Загорание по ритму похоже на сердце – 2 раза, на второй раз сегмент остается белым, текст – темно-серым, загорается следующий.

Comment: Ключ к решению - тег animate. [Пример](https://codepen.io/dimanzver/pen/oNjKwNm). Попробуй поиграться, посмотреть, как тут

Comment: только интересно как увидеть белое на белом

Comment: всё таки косячная прога фигма ..дезигнеров надо побить

Comment: а ещё говорят фигма лучшая прога для дизайна :))

Comment: @MaximLensky, а при чем тут фигма?! Это так нарисовано и я так вставила, сейчас поправлю. Фигма идеальна сейчас для веб дизайна. Сейчас поправлю, так вставила. Меня больше интересует анимация появления

Comment: Лена анимация не проблема - я понимаю что тег animate есть но не ясно как сделана заливка

Comment: @MaximLensky исправила

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любая анимация в svg статичная то есть нету динамики

Так же любая анимация увеличивает объём и вес самого svg документа

Я ни чего не менял просто добавил тег animate

> Смотреть на весь экран

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}

path {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  stroke: #fff;
}

g:hover path {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg width="630" height="45" viewBox="0 0 630 45" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M74.7071 44.521H0.779053L22.0341 22.32L0.779053 0.118988H74.7071L95.9621 22.32L74.7071 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
  <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="a"/> 
    <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="a.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
   </path>
   
      </a>
    </g>


    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M152.214 44.521H80.538L101.793 22.32L80.538 0.118988H152.214L173.469 22.32L152.214 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
  <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="a.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="b"/> 
   <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="b.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>
      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M204.807 44.521H157.868L179.124 22.32L157.868 0.118988H204.807L226.062 22.32L204.807 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
    <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="b.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="c"/> 
     <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="c.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>

      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M294.01 44.521H210.282L231.538 22.32L210.282 0.118988H294.01L315.265 22.32L294.01 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
  <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="c.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="d"/> 
     <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="d.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>
      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M343.138 44.521H300.006L321.261 22.32L300.006 0.118988H343.138L364.394 22.32L343.138 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
  <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="d.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="e"/> 
     <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="e.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>
     </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M433.517 44.521H348.521L369.775 22.32L348.521 0.118988H433.517L454.772 22.32L433.517 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
  <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="e.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="f"/> 
       <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="f.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>
      </a>
    </g>
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M527.8 44.521H438.998L460.254 22.32L438.998 0.118988H527.8L549.056 22.32L527.8 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
   <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="f.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="g"/> 
     <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="g.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>
      </a>
    </g>
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <path class="arrow" d="M607.952 44.521H533.738L554.994 22.32L533.738 0.118988H607.952L629.207 22.32L607.952 44.521Z" fill="white" transform="translate(-2000,0)">
    <animateTransform 
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    values="-2000 0; 0 0"
    dur="2s"
    begin="g.end"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    id="k"/> 
     <animate attributeName="fill" 
             dur="0.34s"
             begin="k.end"
             fill="freeze"
             values="#000; #fff"/>
        </path>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: спасибо, осталось понять как еще с загрузкой страницы  стартовать)